# Would you like it if the question edit page asked you before going to a new page (and losing your data)?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, behavior

Three times in the past 10 minutes I have had to re-type my question's title. Here's what happened:

1. I typed a title, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and got a set of questions. One looked interesting, so I clicked on it. Oops, it's not a new window so my question title is lost.
2. From #1, I hit back, and typed the title again. A list of similar questions comes up, and I accidentally click on one, resulting in the same outcome as #1. I was just about to click on the text box for the question when the question list popped in, and I clicked on one.
3. From #2, I hit back, and typed the question title again. I decided to ask about this on Meta Stack Overflow.

**This is obnoxious**. I think the form should recognize that I'm partway through asking a question and ask me before going to a new page. It seems like it does, but only if I've typed a question body.

Comment: Not saying that this is a solution, but some browsers handle this already (I believe they simply detect that you've entered data into an element within a `<FORM>` and that you haven't submitted it)

Comment: Maybe, but too many "are you sure?" checks can also be an annoyance. There is no one right amount of second-guessing - it's subjective. Most browsers will allow you to open a link in a new tab/window, and it's easy enough to compose an occasional post in a text editor then cut/paste it. I'm not clear on whether "accidentally" means bad aim or something jumped up under your mouse, but even the latter is usually resolved by a fraction of a second more patience. Maybe you need to keep your click reflex a little more under control?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm using FF4, so I assume if a feature like that was baked in to a browser, FF4 would have it. No idea though. I think SO will stop you if you navigate after typing in some of the body of a question.

Comment: @Steve314: the second time a link literally appeared under my mouse. I was aiming for clicking on the textbox. I mentioned that in the OP. Maybe this would be solved by moving the "suggested" questions.

Comment: This is already the case -- once you have started writing the *actual question text* (not just the title), trying to leave the page will pop up a confirmation dialog to make sure you really want to leave.

Comment: @balpha: yes, I know about that. I'm suggesting that that should be extended to the title as well. The title certainly is part of the question.

Comment: @jcollum - as a workaround, can't you write the question text first? I'll agree it's odd that these two fields are treated differently, but it just occurred to me that probably the reason I never had this problem is because I usually write the text first.

Comment: @Steve314: yeah that's a good idea; it'd have to happen to someone a few times first before they try that workaround so that would be a stopgap